# How can I add 1 to each numbers in a file using sed or similar tool?

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file which looks like this :

```
9   3                                       16  2       
10      17                                              
11  R-C R-C                 R-C R-C
```

I would like to replace each digit 'number' with 'number + 1'

Say for example, 9 -> 10, 2 -> 3, 17 -> 18 and so on.

I know that you can use \1 to remember the pattern in sed. But not sure how to add 1 to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `awk` command:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(match($i,/^[0-9]+$/)){$i+=1}}print}' input.txt
```

The result is:

```
10 4 17 3
11 18
12 R-C R-C R-C R-C
```

---

If you need to keep those white spaces, run this command in `vim`:

```
:%s/[0-9]\+/\=submatch(0)+1/g
```

The result is:

```
10   4                                       17  3
11      18
12  R-C R-C                 R-C R-C
```